# Resource lookup for enums

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, enums

```
public enum WeightGoalStatus
{
    InProgress,
    Failed,
    Succeded
}

public static class WeightGoalStatusExtensions
{
    public static string ToLocalizedString(this WeightGoalStatus status)
    {
        return "Localizedstring";//should be code that queries a resource based on the value of the enum
    }
}
```

Is this possible?
also. good idea?
it's basically for a razor view that I need this Resource lookup.cant be showing "INProgress" to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. And we actually do exactly this.

```
public static class WeightGoalStatusExtensions
{
    public static string ToLocalizedString(this WeightGoalStatus status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
           case WeightGoalStatus.InProgress
              return Resources.WeightGoalStatus.InProgress_ToLocalizedString;
           // others
        }
    }
}
```

Just create a resource file as usual, being sure to set CustomTool to ResXFileCodeGenerator.

Also, make sure you set the culture info properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx). A full example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19953/Localizing-NET-Enums).

Comment: ASP.NET MVC will not use this, AFAIK.

Comment: probably not off the shelf, but you may be able to write a custom display attribute which hooks into this.

Answer (score 0):

This will work and I would consider this clean code.

Alternative: Create a resource file with keys such as "Enums.WeightGoalStatus.InProgress" and look up values in that resource file using a dynamic key. This will save you some code. You can also use a static dictionary for that matter, although the existing resources infrastructure is quite good.

Comment: my question is precisely how to query Resources. Please provide sample code :)

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood it. I thought you needed best-practice advice. Search for ".net resource files" on Google to find a *lot* of information on how to query resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the extension class by simply doing the following

ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("ApplicationName.App_LocalResources.Enums", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

string LangEnum = rm.GetString(e_Audits.ToString());